# I get error: Attempt to invoke virtual method .. on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I do not know what am I doing wrong.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference
>   at
>   si.skorajporocena.skorajporocena.PrvaPrijavaActivity$1.onClick(PrvaPrijavaActivity.java:51)

Here is the code:

```
EditText pass;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prva_prijava);

        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(i==0){
                    if (pass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) { // <-- this is the 51 line
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Niste vnesli aktivacijske kode.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).
                                setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        i=1;
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    }
                }
                else if(i>0) {
                    i++;
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);

                    if(i==3){
                        Intent intent;
                        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    //        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: your EditText referance is null check all your ids in xml

Comment: why you set multiple `.toString()`

Comment: himel, it's the same as in code above "etPassword"

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya, that's mistake. But same error still exist.

Comment: Check your Edittext id present in Layout xml file or not

Comment: Munir, it is present.

Comment: @Fisheroid can u show your xml file

Answer (score -1):

Check that the view R.id.etPassword is present in your layout.

Comment: It is present in layout.

Answer (score -1):

Your `pass` variable is null. The most likely cause is a layout error with `R.id.etPassword`

Comment: Everything is okay in layout.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem. 
Problem was that `pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);` was outside an if statement where I need variable `pass`.

Here it is what the code look now:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(i==0){
                    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
                    if (pass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) { // <-- this is the 51 line
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Niste vnesli aktivacijske kode.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).
                                setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        i=1;
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think  you are using id '**etPassword**' from other .xml file. Thats way code compile successfully but run time when click on floating button null pointer exception occurred.